# Python - TypeError: string indices must be integers - Instagram Bot

Tags: python, json

I am working on an instagram bot that automatically likes pictures and follows people. I am having a really hard time getting the JSON to work. Here is the Python:

```
        # Make a list of users who are currently being followed, or have been followed before
    already_followed = []
    for tile in tiles['present']:
        already_followed.append(tile['user_id'])
    for tile in tiles['past']:
        already_followed.append(tile['user_id'])
```

This is my JSON file:

```
    {
  "present": {
    "user": {}
  },
  "past": {
    "user": {}
  }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
  File "Instagram-bot.py", line 95, in <module>
    already_followed.append(tile['user_id'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

If you guys need anything else, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

yes, `tile` is string type i.e. key from the `tiles['present']` dictionary.

try to print `type` of variable `tile` in code.
e.g.

```
>>> a = 123
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = "123"
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

---

sample code:

```
tiles = {
  "present": {
    "user": {"user_id": 123}
  },
  "past": {
    "user": {"user_id": 456}
  }
}

already_followed = []
for tile in tiles['present']:
    already_followed.append(tiles['present'][tile]['user_id'])

for tile in tiles['past']:
        already_followed.append(tiles['past'][tile]['user_id'])


print "already_followed:-", already_followed
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
already_followed:- [123, 456]
```